# Android, onClick, 2 компонета как объеденить для одного нажатия?

Tags: android, android-on-click

У меня есть ImageView и TextView они кликабельны и при нажатии на них должно переходить в с следующие активити (одно и тоже активити). Проблема в коде Java, я использую метод onClick. Как правильно написать код и чтобы он был компактнее?

[image: XML]

Код XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/t_p_1_0"
            style="@style/Tasks_LinearLayout_2"
            android:onClick="onClick">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/t_p_1_1"
                style="@style/Tasks_ImageView_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/t_p_1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/t_p_1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_p_1_2"
                style="@style/Tasks_TextView_1"
                android:text="@string/t_p_1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Код JAVA

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.t_p_1_1:
                    Intent tabtasksprapor1 = new Intent(this, q_p_1.class);
                    startActivity(tabtasksprapor1);
                    break;
                case R.id.t_p_1_2:
                    Intent tabtasksprapor2 = new Intent(this, q_p_1.class);
                    startActivity(tabtasksprapor2);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Не помню, давно было. По `LinearLayout` нельзя отследить `onClick` ?

Comment: да, ловите клик на весь лэйаут t_p_1_0 или в case t_p_1_1 уберите все тело, включая break (оставьте его пустым), тогда выполнение "провалится" во второй case и по итогу не будет дублирования кода

Comment: Оберните все это дело в CardView или же просто сделайте клик на корневой лэйаут да и все.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.t_p_1_0){
                    Intent tabtasksprapor2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), q_p_1.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(tabtasksprapor2);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта. Первый, как по мне предпочтительный, вешать слушатель не на сами кнопки, а на родительский лайаут.

```
findViewById(R.id.t_p_0_1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent tabtasksprapor1 = new Intent(this, q_p_1.class);
                    startActivity(tabtasksprapor1);
                    break;
    }
})
```

Второй вариант, который тут не очень интересен, но его стоит знать. Игра со switch-case, варианты можно группировать

```
switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.t_p_1_1:
        case R.id.t_p_1_2:
            Log.w("W","t_p_1_1 или t_p_1_2 нажата")
            Intent tabtasksprapor1 = new Intent(this, q_p_1.class);
            startActivity(tabtasksprapor1);
            break;
        case R.id.another_view1:
        case R.id.another_view2:
            Log.w("W","view1 или view2 нажата")
            break;
        case R.id.another_view3:
            Log.w("W","view3 нажата")
            break;
    }
```